# search and replace by regex in zend studio

Tags: regex, zend-studio

i have a `.html` file and i am using [zend studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads) for edit `html` and `php` file

i have list in html like

```
    <li style="left: 132px;"><img width="50" height="50" src="img/tribes/1.png"></li>
    <li style="left: 152px;"><img width="50" height="50" src="img/tribes/2.png"></li>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
   <li style="left: 802px;"><img width="50" height="50" src="img/tribe/58.png"></li>
```

and i want to replace  `<li style="left: 132px;">` with simple `<li>` with `regex` how i can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search in zend studio `<li (.*)><img` and replace with `<li><img` see in image

[image]